# Do Clang-Tidy check aliases repeat the same check?

Tags: clang-tidy

When running clang-tidy (with almost all checks enabled) I noticed I've had to suppress a warning under multiple aliases, and sometimes a warning shows up multiple times under different aliases.

Usually this is something I ignore, but after setting the `ShortStatementLines` option for `readability-braces-around-statements` I had to add the same option for its aliases `google-readability-braces-around-statements` and `hicpp-braces-around-statements`.

What I found.

In a bug report (linked below) Nathan James suggests disabling the aliases is preferred to prevent repeated execution.
In a LLVM review for an abandoned change it is suggested that there are configurations that enable both original and aliases of checks, and that there might be differences in configuration between them.

#### This leads to my questions

- Do the aliases always result in duplicate execution of checks, or only in specific circumstances?
  For example when setting `CheckOptions`.
- Wouldn't it then be better to disable all aliases manually in a .clang-tidy file?
  It seems that it should reduce the time needed to run the checks.

#### Links

- [LLVM bug report #44901: cert-dcl37-c / cert-dcl51-cpp aliases should probably also alias AllowedIdentifiers option](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44901)
- [LLVM review D25659: Avoid running aliased checks twice (abandoned)](https://reviews.llvm.org/D25659)
- [LLVM clang-tidy v10.0.0: all aliases](https://releases.llvm.org/10.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/list.html#id110)

Comment: A newer PR but also abandoned: https://reviews.llvm.org/D72566